# Designing a web service to be used by the iPhone and a web client

Tags: ajax, json, api, rest, extjs

I'm designing a web service that serves up JSON through a REST API. This API is currently being used by an iPhone app to do CRUD operations.

My question is, can I design a web client that uses this REST API using nothing more than ExtJS (or some other RIA framework) and HTML pages? In other words, can I create a static HTML page that uses ExtJS to send AJAX calls to the REST API and receive JSON data from it? Or is this thinking too naive and wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is perfectly acceptable as long as you know that your users browser will be able to handle javascript and AJAX accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. I'm concerned because I'm using ASP.NET MVC, and although there's a lot of examples of how the controller passes data to the view, which is then converted to HTML and returned to the client, there's no information on how to use the client to grab data through REST and render it directly.

Comment: So I was concerned that I might've been missing something big that does require server-side generation of HTML before it gets passed off to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! YES! You can use static html and js files, served by any web server, to build an Ext JS application. Ext JS is *very* happy to talk REST and JSON to your web service.

Build your Ext JS application *outside* of ASP.NET MVC. You don't need it.